# Ruby on Rails add model to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Here are my models:

```
class Hour < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :time, :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :hour, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
hour = Hour.new
#add values to the hour object here
hour.save!
project = Project.find :first
project.hour.add hour #how do I actually do this?
projet.save!
```

This throws an error.  How do I add a model to an association?

I'm coming from a PHP background with Doctrine2.  In Doctrine2 I would do something like:

```
$projects->getHours()->add($hour);
```

Also, I've read these docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.  They seem to cover everything on how to create associations, but I can't find info on how to work with them!  Any good docs on how to work with associations?

Answer (score 1):

First, correct name,

```
has_many :hours
```

then,

```
project.hours << hour
```

4.3.1.2 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like an array:

```
project.hours << hour
```

but often it feels more natural to build the new model directly using the association:

```
hour = project.hours.build({ your: "...",  attributes: "...", here: "..."})
# Do more stuff with hour
project.save!
```

(The `build` method behaves like `new`, but for technical reasons it must be named `build` here)

Or in case you want to immedately save the model:

```
project.hours.create({ your: "...",  attributes: "...", here: "..."})
```

The Rails documentation has a list of the "magic" methods of associations. Have a look at the [`has_many` Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).